# In DBPedia, what is the difference between "nt" and "nq" datasets?

Tags: dataset, dbpedia

In DBpedia datasets, I notice there are two datasets provided, what is the difference between both of them.

http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads36

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried downloading the two types of archives?

Answer (score 1):

From that page:

> The downloads are provided as N-Triples and N-Quads, where the N-Quads version contains additional provenance information for each statement. All files are bz2 packed

So nt => [N-Triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Triples), nq => [N-Quads](http://sw.deri.org/2008/07/n-quads/).

Comment: And now the page says so explicitly...  :-)